# How to install Windows 7 Bootcamp using iso file (without USB/DVD)?

Tags: bootcamp, usb, optical-drive, dual-boot

I have a MacBook Pro and I need to install Windows 7 besides Mac OS X so I can play games on it.

The problem is that I don't have a USB stick or DVD to copy the Win7 iso image like Bootcamp requires.

Can I install Win7 using an internal partition of my hard disk?

Comment: It's important what MBP you have. Please tell us the output of "ioreg | grep MacBook"

Comment: 2011 MacBook Pro

Comment: Why not just buy a USB stick? I'm not sure how much space you need to fit the ISO, but 16 GB sticks are as low as $10 on Amazon.

Comment: This approach will most likely not work without a _lot_ of elbow grease.  A 4GB USB-key is not very expensive and most likely the simplest way to do it.  I believe that the "Install Windows by PXE-booting" option requires Windows Server to be running and set up properly on your local network.

Answer (score 1):

Here might be a solution :

1. Create a new partition (at least 8Gig)
2. Copy the iso on it
3. Try booting on it
4. If it works reboot and create a new Bootcamp partition
5. Try installing Windows on the bootcamp partition

If this don't work, You'll need a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows machine and an Administrator account they try this [Microsoft Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

A convoluted way if you do not have another Windows machine would be to install a VM like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), use the iso to install Windows in that and then use the MS tool mentioned above. Actually just having Windows in a VM might be sufficient for you depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't have USB or DVD !

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that Virtualisation Software is no match for Boot Camp if you want to play games. You definitely want Bootcamp, and not Virtualbox, Parallels or VmWare Fusion.

Comment: @Simon the question is how to get a ISO so that you can install Bootcamp - not on how to host Windows

Comment: @Mark Ah ok, I miss understood, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the ISO File
2. Find the 'boot' file
3. Click the 'bcd' program
4. Wait 3-7 Seconds, A Window should appear.
5. Partion the Disk.
6. Complete!

Enjoy Windows or Linux!

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing your main macintosh HD drive get a windows install disk install it onto the new empty drive.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.